# Referencing class from another component

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs

I am trying to target sideBar in my app.js component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    //initial state
    this.state = {
        plants: {},
        order: {},
        showSideBar: true,
    };
    this.loadPlants = this.loadPlants.bind(this);
    this.addToOrder = this.addToOrder.bind(this);
    this.showSideBar = this.showSideBar.bind(this);
}

showSideBar(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.sideBar.classList.toggle("show");
    this.setState({
        showSideBar: true,
    })
}
```

It currently lives in cart.js here:

```
render() {
    const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);
    const total = orderIds.reduce((prevTotal,key) => {
        const plants = this.props.plants[key];
        const count = this.props.order[key];
        const isAvailable = true;

        if(isAvailable) {
            return prevTotal + (count * plant.price || 0);
        }
    }, []);
    return(
        <aside className="sideBar" ref={ref => this.sideBar = ref}>
            <div className="order-wrap">
                <h1>Your Cart</h1>
                <ul className="order">
                    {orderIds.map(this.renderOrder)}
                    <li className="total">
                        <strong>Total:</strong>
                        {formatPrice(total)}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="close-btn" onClick={this.showSideBar}>
                    <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Place Order"/>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

Any ideas as to how I can reference the sideBar class correctly in app.js? "this.sideBar.classList.toggle("show");" gives me an error that says classList is not defined.

Comment: is sideBar a React component?

Comment: @EJMason Nope, not a React component. It's just a class we've declared to toggle a sidebar/shopping cart.

Comment: can you show more codes

Comment: @JunbangHuang Added more code above!